# How can I refresh the resource file for an EXE?

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder.net

I am trying to include a custom icon in one of our existing powerbuilder applications. I was able to do this by building a runtime library with the resource file included.

It looks like developers before me didn't have this problem as I do not have to build with the resource file in order to deploy code changes.

**What are some of the alternatives to building a runtime library with a resource file?** We are using PowerBuilder 11.

Comment: By runtime library do you mean PBD files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include just an icon, you do not need to build a specific `.pbd`.

Mention your icon file into the `.pbr` resource file associated with your deployment project (in the first tab settings, where you select to produce either pcode or machine code). It will be included directly into the `.exe`.

Comment: Thanks. PowerBuilder is a fickle beast, and I have yet to learn all its tricks.